# Right to Left (RTL) text in XWPFDocument (Apache POI)

Tags: apache-poi, right-to-left

I could not find a way to make a RTL paragraph in Docx using XWPFDocument (Apache POI) in my Java program. Here's my code that generates the XWPFDocument.

```
    XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();
    title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    title.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    title.setWordWrap(true);
    XWPFRun titleRun = title.createRun();
    titleRun.setText(reportDesign.getName());

    XWPFTable s = document.createTable(resultList.size()+1, columnList.size());
    // declare a row object reference
    XWPFTableRow r = s.getRow(0);
    // declare a cell object reference
    XWPFTableCell c = null;
    // create columnList.size() cells (0-(columnList.size()-1))
    for (int cellnum = 0; cellnum < columnList.size(); cellnum++) {
        c = r.getCell(cellnum);
        c.setColor("c9c9c9");
        c.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        c.setText(columnList.get(cellnum).getColumnHeader());
    }
    // create a sheet with resultList.size() rows (1-resultList.size())
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < resultList.size(); rownum++) {
        // create a row
        r = s.getRow(rownum+1);

        // create columnList.size() cells (0-(columnList.size()-1))
        for (int cellnum = 0; cellnum < columnList.size(); cellnum++) {
            c = r.getCell(cellnum);
            Object value = resultList.get(rownum).get(columnList.get(cellnum).getColumnKey());
            if (value != null) {
                c.setText(value.toString());
            } else {
                c.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Would you please help me? Is there a logical way to extend POI (or similar solution) for gaining this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that I found till now is using a template document.

Using this method, you make an empty document that "Normal" style in it, is configured to be RTL. This way, everything in your document will be RTL.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(AbstractWordView.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("empty.docx"));
```

Comment: how can I set UTF-8 , by default when I convert word to pdf , Pdf text is spoiled, such as "ب ی ت ر ت" instead of "ترتیب"
I used this code :
options.fontEncoding("UTF-8")
But instead of making it right. All letters disappeared

Comment: Your issue is not related to this question, as it's about Docx format. I don't know about PDF using Apache POI.