# trying to set arabic sentence in word using Apache poi?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

i'am trying to generate a word document using apache poi api, and i want to set an arabic sentence into the word, but the words didn't stay on the order !!! for instead of "شهادة بالملك" i get بالملك شهادة

```
public class word {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();

    try {

    XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = docx.createParagraph();   
    XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();   
    tmpRun.setText("شهادة بالملك");
    tmpRun.setFontSize(18);  
    tmpRun.setFontFamily("Calibri (Corps)");
    tmpRun.setBold(true);
    tmpRun.setColor("003894");
    tmpParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    tmpRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
    tmpParagraph.setSpacingAfter(300);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Word2.docx");
    docx.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your words are exactly the same...

Comment: I edit my question it was just a mistake

Comment: Arabic is right to left instead of left to right.  Does XWPFDocument know that the writing direction is changed?

Comment: just cant fing any command doing what you had proposed....(tmpRun(reverse(word)))

Comment: mm sorry I meant that you can implement a `reverse` method by yourself and then `tmpRun.setText(reverse("شهادة بالملك"))`. It is not a nice solution but that's a possible fix in case you don't find anything else

Comment: NO, how can i tell him to write from right to left ?!!

Comment: It is not even sure that such a feature has been implemented... Programs or libraries cannot be adapted to every languages in the world.

Comment: i'am sure that apache poi can support this, and i should just change the direction right to left as Andersen said i just should find the command doing this !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right to Left (RTL) text in XWPFDocument (Apache POI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171777/right-to-left-rtl-text-in-xwpfdocument-apache-poi)

Comment: AbstractWordView can not be resolved as type !!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the answer :

```
public class word {

    public enum TextOrientation {
          LTR,
          RTL
       }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

    XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();

    try {

    XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = docx.createParagraph();   
    XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();   
    tmpRun.setText("شهادة بالملك");
    tmpRun.setFontSize(18);  
    tmpRun.setFontFamily("Calibri (Corps)");
    tmpRun.setBold(true);
    tmpRun.setColor("003894");
    tmpParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    tmpRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
    tmpParagraph.setSpacingAfter(300);
    setOrientation(tmpParagraph, TextOrientation.RTL);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Word2.docx");
    docx.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void setOrientation(XWPFParagraph par, TextOrientation orientation) {
          if ( par.getCTP().getPPr()==null ) {
              par.getCTP().addNewPPr();
          }
          if ( par.getCTP().getPPr().getBidi()==null ) {
             par.getCTP().getPPr().addNewBidi();
          }
          par.getCTP().getPPr().getBidi().setVal(orientation==TextOrientation.RTL?STOnOff.ON:STOnOff.OFF);
       }
}
```