# How do i change docx4j text direction with java?

Tags: java, text, right-to-left, docx4j

I am writting text to a docx document using docx4j i want to change default text direction to right-to-left , this is my code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
mainDocumentPart.addParagraphOfText("some plain text");
File exportFile = new File("test.docx");
wordPackage.save(exportFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suggested to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/document/index.html). Please check [this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-word-with-apache-poi) page for a tutorial and use a template file for your goal as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172068/1055591).

Answer (score 0):

In the WordML/OpenXML file format, r2l is a boolean property on a run: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/rtl.html

So:

```
 // Create object for rtl
BooleanDefaultTrue booleandefaulttrue = wmlObjectFactory.createBooleanDefaultTrue(); 
rpr.setRtl(booleandefaulttrue);
```

You set rPr on a run (R object), for example:

```
RPr rpr = wmlObjectFactory.createRPr(); 
r.setRPr(rpr);
```

In the above:

```
org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory wmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();
```

You can generate code for docx4j by creating a sample document in Word which contains what you want, then using the docx4j webapp or docx4j Helper Word AddIn.