# Flipped characters docx to pdf , java

Tags: java, pdf, arabic, xdocreport

iam using Opensagres XDocReport convert docx to pdf, the result i got is flipped arabic characters

instead of being

السلام عليكم

its showed as

[image: image of actual result]

Comment: Could it be related to a left-to-right setting in the converter?

Comment: @Alfabravo can you give hint how to make it right to left?

Comment: XDocReport is built on top of an old version of iText. iText didn't introduce full support for Arabic up until iText 7. See for instance [How to convert HTML containing Arabic/Hebrew characters to PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-convert-html-containing-arabichebrew-characters-pdf) iText as such doesn't convert DOCX to PDF, only HTML to PDF. iText 7 is open source (AGPL), but the add-on with Arabic support is closed source.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the library's issues, [seems like](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/142) this one is not yet solved :/

I would look into the code and how can you [set properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171777/right-to-left-rtl-text-in-xwpfdocument-apache-poi) for Apache POI (which is the one underneath) or for FOP (the PDF serializer). SOrry I can't help any further